# Vanilla JS mobile menu works on chrome but not on Firefox or Edge (no toggling)

Tags: javascript

I use the following code [in my site](http://contfix.co.il) to display a mobile menu in viewports equal to, or under 768px.

The code works perfectly fine in Chrome but not in Firefox and Edge, where, after resizing, the menu just won't open (no toggling). Why?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{

    let clicks = 0;
    let menu = document.querySelector('#menu-mainmenu'); // Menu identifier.
    let menuButton = document.querySelector('.menuButton'); // Button class in pagebuilder.

    let mobileBehavior = ()=>{
        menu.style.display = 'none';
        menuButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            clicks++;
            if (clicks % 2) {
                menu.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                menu.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    };

    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        mobileBehavior();
    }

    // Event cleanups:

    window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>{
        if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
            clicks = 1; // Prevent menuButton double clicking.
            mobileBehavior(); // Display mobile menu both on bootstrapping and resize.
        } else if (window.innerWidth >= 769) {

            menu.style.display = 'block'; // Prevent display:none by mobile mode.
        }
    });

});
```

Note: No console errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you resize the screen you add the click event to the same menu element, so you should take the `addEventListener` outside of the mobileBehavior function and just exec the *mobileBehavior* function to show or hide the menu, but no for attaching event listener, as it may overload the listener to the menu.

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{

    let clicks = 0;
    let menu = document.querySelector('#menu-mainmenu'); // Menu identifier.
    let menuButton = document.querySelector('.menuButton'); // Button class in pagebuilder.

menuButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            clicks++;
            if (clicks % 2) {
                menu.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                menu.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });

    let mobileBehavior = ()=>{
        menu.style.display = 'none';
    };

    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        mobileBehavior();
    }

    // Event cleanups:

    window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>{
        if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
            clicks = 1; // Prevent menuButton double clicking.
            mobileBehavior(); // Display mobile menu both on bootstrapping and resize.
        } else if (window.innerWidth >= 769) {

            menu.style.display = 'block'; // Prevent display:none by mobile mode.
        }
    });

});
```

Here you have a working example code [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rb5xkjrt/)